Is std::move_only_function thread safe?
Is it safe to call a std::move_only_function object in one thread and replace the function it points to in another thread?
My code:
#include <future>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::move_only_function<void()> fn = []{};

    auto future1 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ fn(); });
    auto future2 = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]{ fn = []{}; });

    future1.get();
    future2.get();
}

I don't care if the old or the new function is called. Also I know that fn always holds a valid function.

No, because it is not an atomic. And it doesn't use atomics.

In general a function is NOT threadsafe unless it explicitly states that it is. (From the top of my head I only know that initializing a static local variable is explicitly threadsafe) from C++11 onward

This is what the standard says on thread safety of standard library types in the absence of specific wording to the contrary. The short version is "non-const methods may modify this, its parameters, or anything indirectly accessible via this or its parameters. Const methods may not modify anything." You are invoking a non-const methods (operator()) on one thread, while accessing the object from another thread, without synchronization, which is a data race.

No it is not safe.
The assignment operator (std::move_only_function::operator=) is not guaranteed to be atomic.
Therefore you can have a context switch in the middle of it, leaving the std::move_only_function object in an invalid state which the other thread will attempt to invoke leading to undefined-behavior.

The biggest problem is that if small buffer optimization is used (and on MSVC its size is 5 pointers), if your lambda captures anything and it was replaced while the function was running then your running lambda captures will be corrupted.
Not only do you want its assignment to be thread-safe, you don't want it to be re-assigned while it is running either, you will want to move out of it before you call it or lock it with a RW lock while executing it.
A better option is to use an atomic (shared) pointer to the move only function if you want thread-safety.

std::move_only_function itself does not provide thread safety guarantees, you can use it safely in a multi-threaded context if you handle synchronization and access control correctly.
